# php7: echo "&amp" returns & versus &amp

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "&amp";
?>
```

result: &

How do I get php to return &amp versus &?

I am attempting to update AMP content. The standard what of posting variables is to append them with an ampersand. The AMP arguments include amp_action, amp_ts and amp_url_signature. PHP is removing the amp following the &, so I cannot perform the update.

Some other examples:

```
<?php
echo "&"."amp_ts";
?>
```

result: &_ts

```
<?php
echo "&". "\amp";
?>
```

result: &\amp

```
<?php
echo "&\\"."amp";
?>
```

result: &\amp

Comment: do you run this code in console? for browser it's expected to process HTML entities but for CLI it would be a bug

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I am running this through a browser. I forgot about how HTML processes special character entities.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `echo "&amp;";` just get the ampersand alone ("&") and `echo "&amp;amp";` to get "&amp"
- note the use of the semicolons

Answer (score 1):

you can use:-

```
echo "&ampamp";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
echo "&amp;";
```